# How to create dynamic pages with .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to know what I need to put in the .htaccess to do the following.

When people call one of my pages, for example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/cooks/New-York_NY.html
http://www.mydomain.com/cooks/Plantation_FL.html
```

that it would create these pages on the fly from a file called `cookscities.php`.

Then the page `cookscities.php` would pull the values from the URL for the city and state and place it on the page.

So for sample requested page: `http www.mydomain.com/cooks/New-York_NY.html` my page `cookscities.php` inserts value of URL on page content city value but remove the "-" if there is one and also places the state 2 letters.

So the page title would say:

```
Find Cooks in New York NY
```

Answer (score 1):

In .htaccess add:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /cooks/(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/cookscities.php?val=$1 [L]
```

This matches any URL beginning with /cooks/ and calls cookscities.php, passing in the part after "/cooks/" as the GET variable `val`.

In cookscities.php you could have:

```
<?php
list($city, $state) = explode('_', $_GET['val']);
$city = str_replace('-', ' ', $city);

echo "Find Cooks in $city $state";
?>
```

Comment: Why are you exploding rather than configuring the `RewriteRule` in the first place to split it up into multiple `GET` parameters on the URL?

Comment: @Treffynnon: No particular reason. 2 matches in the rewrite rule would work also.

Comment: @qbert220 what is I need to post on the page $city which would write New York but in another place I need it to write New+York for google maps, how do I do that?

Comment: @Gonzolo: Presumably you are encoding the string to pass as a URL to Google maps. If this is the case, use `urlencode($city)` to return a URL encoded string. This will not only replace spaces with plus signs, but also replace other special characters with escaped equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done by using mod_rewrite: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/